# Azure Mobile Service Nodejs on Local Machine Error with Push

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am following Azure's Mobile Quickstart Tutorial (Xamarin.Android) and I was able to have the Facebook Authentication and Push Notification running.

Now, I wanted to know how to have a local development environment or have the Mobile App Service (Nodejs) run on my local machine instead (not on Azure Cloud). And I followed this tutorial:
https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-2-local-development/

However, things break just after I open the app. See screenshots below:
[image]

Error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: Cannot PUT /push/installations/cc69e3d2-5d18-4077-a23a-56a845a73698
```

Couple of notes:

**- This app works as it should if I connect it to the remote app service on Azure Cloud.**

**- Yes, I have the app server (nodejs) cloned in my local machine - installed required modules, and is running as it should (screenshot)**
[image]

```
// This is a base-level Azure Mobile App SDK.
var express = require('express'),
    azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');

// Set up a standard Express app
var app = express();

// If you are producing a combined Web + Mobile app, then you should handle
// anything like logging, registering middleware, etc. here

// Configuration of the Azure Mobile Apps can be done via an object, the
// environment or an auxiliary file.  For more information, see
// http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#configuration
var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true,
    // Explicitly enable swagger support. UI support is enabled by
    // installing the swagger-ui npm module.
    // swagger: true,
    // App will use MS_SqliteFilename or MS_TableConnectionString to choose the SQLite or SQL data provider
    data: {
        dynamicSchema: true
    }
});

// Import the files from the tables directory to configure the /tables endpoint
mobileApp.tables.import('./tables');

// Import the files from the api directory to configure the /api endpoint
mobileApp.api.import('./api');

// Initialize the database before listening for incoming requests
// The tables.initialize() method does the initialization asynchronously
// and returns a Promise.
mobileApp.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
        app.use(mobileApp);    // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Listen for requests
    });
```

**- And also yes, I changed the mobile app client's needed ApplicationURL to the one I have running locally (screenshot)**

[image]

```
...

const string applicationURL = @"http://192.168.1.221:3000";

const string localDbFilename = "newlocalstore.db";

protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_To_Do);

    CurrentPlatform.Init();
    ...
```

**- Lastly, I have my IP address already white-listed on the firewall setting of the MS SQL Server. So it shouldn't be an issue since I was also able to fully up my local app service (nodejs).**

What do you think causes the error?

Comment: is your `node.js` code binding to that same ip/port (192.168.1.211:3000) as your C# code is using?

Comment: FYI: Using screenshots for exceptions/code/etc... are bad form, they are not indexable/searchable, tough to read, etc.. most people will just skip your question

Comment: hi @SushiHangover - where can I find or change this binding? But if you mean the code on the app.js - yes, it is on port 3000. The ip address is the local ip address of my machine so that my emulator can access to it.

Comment: And yes, thanks for pointing about the screenshots out - will post the code itself here to make it searchable.

Comment: in your javascript that node is running will be the ip/port binding for whatever you are using; socket, httplistener, etc...

Comment: Yes, i used port 3000 and it is running correctly because when I go to my localhost:3000 it shows me the azure mobile service static website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run locally, you must provide ALL the connection strings required - including ones that are automatically generated for you in the cloud.  In this case, you have not defined the Notification Hubs connection string in the local
environment.

Go to Kudu (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) and look at the environment variables for connection strings.  They are rather obvious when you look for them.  Make sure you have all the connection strings defined as the same environment variables.

Comment: Awesome man! I edited the configuration on the azureMobile.js to add "notifications". Used the variables as in showed in Kudu, then woala! It works! Thanks! :)